# NodeJS: async module: passing arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, asynccallback, node-async

I'm trying to pass arguments into a function in a NodeJS async queue with a callback. I can pass one argument correctly, but it fails for two.

Extract (abc is triggered by a HTTP POST request):

```
var queue = async.queue(doStuff, 5); 

var abc = function(request, response)
{
    queue.push(request, response, callback); 
}

var doStuff = function(request, response, callback)
{
    promiseChain...
    then(function(result) {
        //get stuff with result
        callback(response, stuff);
    }).close(); 
}

var callback = function(response, data)
{ response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}); response.end(data); }
```

If I remove the response (or request) argument from the doStuff definition, then I can make it work. With two arguments + the callback, it throws any error saying the 2nd argument must be a callback function.

The doStuff function needs the request variable. The callback function needs to the response variable. Any idea how to implement? I tried put request and response into an array of objects but the array didn't pass into `doStuff` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I remove the response (or request) argument from the doStuff definition, then I can make it work. With two arguments + the callback, it throws any error saying the 2nd argument must be a callback function.

[`async.queue().push()`](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/README.md#queue) only takes 2 arguments, `push(task, [callback])`. This is why you're only ever getting the first argument passed to your worker. Instead of flattening your parameters when passing them to `queue.push()` pass them in as an object

```
queue.push({ req: request, res: response}, callback);
```

Then in `doStuff`

```
var doStuff = function(params, callback) {
    // Get our params from the object passed through
    var request = params.req;
    var response = params.res;

    promiseChain...
    then(function(result) {
        //get stuff with result
        callback(response, stuff);
    }).close(); 
}
```